Why is this C code slower with OpenMP than when single-threaded?
I'm new to multithreading, and I thought it would be good practice to try to calculate pi via Monte Carlo sampling. But when I was testing, I found my code runs a lot slower when compiled with -fopenmp than without. Here's the parallelized area:
    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(success, random)
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        unsigned int temp;
        fread(&temp, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, random);
        double xval = (double)temp / UINT_MAX;
        fread(&temp, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, random);
        double yval = (double)temp / UINT_MAX;
        if((xval*xval + yval*yval) < 1){
            #pragma omp atomic
            ++success;
        }
    }

I've tried to cut shared variables to a minimum. I've also played around with different schedule values to try and eliminate false sharing. That may have helped a bit but I'm not sure. It was still way slower than single threaded. Looking at gprof, I noticed that the program spent a lot of time in fread, so I tried using rand() instead of reading from /dev/random but that ended up being even slower. It also spends a lot of time in locking functions. Is the atomic statement really what's holding it up? If so, what would be a better way to increment it? I've also tried a reduction on success with little effect.
Here's the gprof output as well:
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 37.88      0.63     0.63                             __lll_lock_wait_private
 26.67      1.07     0.44                             fread
 23.64      1.46     0.39                             __lll_lock_wake_private
  4.85      1.54     0.08        3    26.67    26.67  main
  1.82      1.57     0.03                             _IO_file_xsgetn
  1.82      1.60     0.03                             _IO_sgetn
  1.82      1.63     0.03                             gomp_team_barrier_wait_end
  0.61      1.64     0.01                             fputs
  0.61      1.65     0.01                             read
  0.30      1.65     0.01                             __libc_cleanup_pop_restore


File-operations are more or less serial. If multiple threads try to read from the same file, the read-requests will share one single queue. A common solution is to read the whole file into memory first, then let the threads work on their own slice of that memory.

Besides that, always check for failure when you do an operation that can fail. Like reading from a file.

Oh and why are you using a file to read data when you calculate pi? What file are you reading from? What is the data in the file?

The file is /dev/random. I'm using it to generate a random point in 2d space from [0,0] to [1,1], and then checking whether that point is closer than distance 1 to [0,0]. When you do that, you're essentially scattering a bunch of points and only keeping the ones within a quarter-circle of radius 1. So as n goes to infinity, the ratio of points within 1 to total points approaches pi/4. But anyway, as I said, I've tried using the standard library to get the numbers instead and it wasn't any faster. Is there a better way to do it?

@Some programmer dude I think I'll try what you said, reading a bunch of values into memory at once with a master thread and then letting the threads each use their own bit of it. I'm worried that I might run into false sharing doing that, though. Will keep this thread updated!

You could probably improve the performance by reading two integers in one fread() operation (use an array), halving the number of calls to fread().  You could even read batches of 4, 8, 16 or more integers and process the results.  That doesn't answer your question, but I/O operations are serialized, as already explained, and your code spends a lot of time locking and unlocking code, with each thread probably blocking other threads while holding the lock.  Reducing the number of I/O calls should help. […continued…]

[…continuation…]  You could also consider using a thread-local variable for the success counter so the #pragma omp atomic isn't executed as often.  I'm not sure how OpenMP handles (creates, uses, destroys) thread-local variables, but I assume it must.  When the parallel loop ends, you'd use atomic additions to add each thread's counts (of tries and successes) to the global result.

The right way to handle success is a reduction. But in all cases the bottleneck of your code are the fread.  Calling rand() instead may help, or not, depending on the specific implementation of your compiler (some of them protect it with a mutex, which will kill the parallelism)

btw, which potential false sharing are you talking about? I can't see any here.

Using reduction(+:success) instead of shared(success) will make success thread-local as @JonathanLeffler suggested and sum up the thread-local values at the end of the parallel region. The real issue is polling fread from multiple threads.

Regarding your false-sharing concern: You are worried about a conflict in accessing a book in the library next door, while your current problem is flying to Paris to check the same information before returning to the class room with the information. The whole class has only one plane available.

Update: I've moved off of using /dev/urandom. I'm now using r_random with a separate state for each thread. The states are in an array, but I've padded them to my cache line size, and aligned them as well. They are the only shared values. I'm using a reduction on success. The program is much faster now, but the single threaded version is still about twice as fast. I'm honestly at a loss for what to do at this point. Should I make a new thread or just edit this one? I'm not sure on what the etiquette is on this site.

The loop iteration calls fread twice and it has an assumption that the two calls to fread won't be interleaved with two calls to fread by a parallel thread. That assumption is incorrect.

FYI: For Monte-Carlo you generally want high quality random numbers (i.e. uncorrelated, unbiased), so for both the generation and sampling of a particular distribution (even the uniform distribution) I would recommend using more sophisticated solutions like the GNU Scientific Library.

Questions can and should be edited to improve their quality and usefulness to the community. In cases like this it is not always easy to determine if updating the question is a good idea as it seems to completely change the issue at hand. If someone took the time to answer your question, you should certainly not edit it in a way that invalidates the answer and instead post a new question (with clear differentiation from the previous one). You generally don't have to be that careful with comments on your question (somewhat answering it). You can also self-answer.

Please include information about your hardware, compiler and compiler-flags in questions about performance/optimization. Especially with standards like C and OpenMP, the implementation of these standards is an important detail. Including a minimal reproducible example is a good idea, so people can do performance experiments.

What you need is an efficient parallel, random number generator, rather than performing read operations. See https://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf which is now implemented in many maths libraries.
